# How to update a bokeh plot inside vscode jupyter notebook?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

How do you update a bokeh plot inside a Jupyter notebook in VSCode, other than clearing output and redrawing?

Bokeh provides a function called `push_notebook` for such type of updates (docs [here](https://%20https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/io.html#bokeh.io.push_notebook)), but I am running the code below and the plot it is never updated, as shown in the screenshot. I have `bokeh-3.0.3` and `jupyter_bokeh-3.0.7`

Is this functionality supported? What extra configuration is needed, then?

```py
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show
from bokeh.io import push_notebook
from time import sleep

# Enable inline plotting for Jupyter Notebook
output_notebook()

# Create a Bokeh plot
plot = figure(title='Update Example', x_axis_label='Time', y_axis_label='Value')
line = plot.line([], [])
handle = show(plot, notebook_handle=True)

# Simulate updates with a sleep function
for i in range(10):
    # Some simulated data update
    x_data = [j for j in range(i + 1)]
    y_data = [j**2 for j in range(i + 1)]

    # Update the Bokeh plot
    line.data_source.data = {'x': x_data, 'y': y_data}
    push_notebook(handle=handle)

    # Sleep for a short duration to simulate a delay
    sleep(0.5)
```

[image: screenshot of vscode]

Comment: I believe panel.holoviz.org can wrap bokeh plots to make them display with live updates in vscode, but I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Hmmm...I just ran your code in JupyterLab where I knew Bokeh for updating was working based on a notebook I aldready had working there. Your code works well there. Maybe you are missing something in your environment? You can try it yourself by going [here](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/fomightez/communication_voila/master?labpath=notebooks%2FBokeh%20that%20works%20in%20classic%20notebook%20interface%20and%20JupyterLab%20June%202022.ipynb) and then when you see a notebook come up, don't run it. Instead use 'File' > 'New` > 'Notebook' to make a new notebook and paste in and run your code.